# Has anyone used react-awesome-button in Typescript successfully?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

react-awesome-button is a really nice npm package, and I really want to use it in my React with Typescript project, but since it's untyped, I am having problems.

I tried everything:

1. adding a .d.ts file in src.
2. // @ts-ignore on top of the line where I use ...

If you have successfully used this package with Typescript, please let me know. Thanks.